# Why does Virtual Basic say it cannot access the file?

Tags: vb.net, file, save

I am creating a solid edge macro that saves a 3D file in solid edge in three different types simultaneously.
owever, I am new to vb.net some I am having some difficulty.

When I run the program, the first pop up says "this file already exists, do you want to overwrite it?".

The next pop up says "cannot access this file" and then the program stops.
Why can vb.net not access the file? It is open in solid edge in the background.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub saveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveBtn.Click
            Dim objApplication As SolidEdgeFramework.Application = Nothing
            Dim objDocument As SolidEdgeFramework.SolidEdgeDocument = Nothing
            Dim objPropertySets As SolidEdgeFramework.PropertySets = Nothing
            Dim objProperties As SolidEdgeFramework.Properties = Nothing
            Dim objProperty As SolidEdgeFramework.Property = Nothing
            Dim FileName As String
            Dim i, j As Integer
            Dim NewFileName1 As String
            Dim NewFileName2 As String
            Dim NewFileName3 As String
            Dim Extensions(2) As String
            Extensions(0) = ".step"
            Extensions(1) = ".x_t"
            Extensions(2) = ".igs"
            Try
                objApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject("SolidEdge.Application")
                objDocument = objApplication.ActiveDocument
                objPropertySets = objDocument.Properties
                For i = 1 To objPropertySets.Count
                    objProperties = objPropertySets.Item(i)
                    For j = 1 To objProperties.Count
                        objProperty = objProperties.Item(j)
                    Next
                Next
                FileName = objProperty.Name
                NewFileName1 = FileName & Extensions(0)
                NewFileName2 = FileName & Extensions(1)
                NewFileName3 = FileName & Extensions(2)
                objDocument.SaveAs("C:\Folder", NewFileName1)
                objDocument.SaveAs("C:\Folder", NewFileName2)
                objDocument.SaveAs("C:\Folder", NewFileName3)
                'objDocument.SaveAs(NewFileName1)
                'objDocument.SaveAs(NewFileName2)
                'objDocument.SaveAs(NewFileName3)
            Catch ex As Exception
                txt.Text = "           Error"
            Finally
                If Not (objDocument Is Nothing) Then
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objDocument)
                    objDocument = Nothing
                End If
                If Not (objApplication Is Nothing) Then
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objApplication)
                    objApplication = Nothing
                End If

            End Try
        End Sub
        End Class
```

Comment: The reason it cannot overwrite is most likely because you say it is open in another program already as well. Then the file is basically locked for editing.

Comment: You are not using SaveAs() correctly.  The first argument must be the *file name*, not the folder name.  Right now you are trying to overwrite the folder with a file, that will never work.  Use objDocument.SaveAs(Path.Combine("C:\Folder", NewFileName1))

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Quick question. Won't this just save the document with "C:\Folder\NewFileName1" as its file name? I would like to save NewFileName1 in location C:\Folder. Is this possible?

Comment: It is a variable, not a string literal.  The only mistake you could make it is not trying it.

Comment: Okay great thank you! Path.Combine didn't work for me (maybe not supported in Visual Basic 2008) but simply adding C:\Folder\ to NewFileName did.